# Add search criteria using Content Navigator plugin on click of Search Button in Search Template

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

In IBM content Navigator, i need to add one additional search criteria to all search template on click of Search button (for example strStatus="In Progress").

And only documents which matches this criteria should be displayed in search Result.

This i want to do using IBM content Navigator plugin and this search criteria should not be visible in any search template.

Can someone help me, how I can archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to implement a request filter for `p8/search` service. This should allow you to inject the additional search criteria into the request before it is executed.

See https://github.com/ibm-ecm/ibm-content-navigator-samples/blob/master/UserColumnSettingsPlugin/src/com/ibm/ecm/extension/ColumnsDisplayedRequestFilter.java for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the Responce.

I am using RequestFilter for /p8/service.
But how can i set search criteria for property when its not available in selected search Template.
Can you pease provide code if available

Answer (score 0):

You don't need plugin for this requirement. In search template designer there is an option to make the property hidden. So you can have your search criteria with your property and value and make that property hidden.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).